# iphone simulator using multi-touch problem

Tags: iphone, multi-touch

i know in iphone simulator to input using multi-touch, hold down the OPT key while using the mouse. will see two virtual fingertips.and move the mouse to pinch in and out.
my problem is in simulator,these two fingertips will only be overlap at the center all the time, if  i jus want move one finger and another finger fix at a point,rather move two fingertips together how to achieve this in iphone simulator?in other word i want this two virtual finger can be overlap anywhere on the screen but not just center

Comment: I'd like to remove my answer as I was clearly wrong. :) I suggest giving user epatel the creds he deserves.

Answer (score 94):

If you press Shift-Option they will also move *together* with a static distance.